# Kubernetes Go API

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have some questions about the golang API for kubernetes.

1. which one should I use? k8s.io/client-go or k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client? What's the difference?
2. I want to get list of all pods and then listen to add/update/delete events, what's the difference between using the api.Pods("").Watch method and using an informer?
3. I'm using the API from inside the cluster, how can I fetch the name of the node I'm currently in? is it just the hostname of the machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> which one should I use? k8s.io/client-go or k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client?

Use `k8s.io/client-go`.

> what's the difference between using the api.Pods("").Watch method and using an informer?

The informer is essentially a shared cache, reducing the load on the API server. Unless you're doing something trivial, this is the preferred way.

> how can I fetch the name of the node I'm currently in?

Use [k8s.io/api/core/v1.Node](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#Node), see for example [this code](https://github.com/openshift-talks/k8s-go/blob/master/client-go-basic/main.go).

BTW, a colleague of mine and myself gave a workshop on this topic (using the Kube API with Go) last week at GopherCon UK—maybe the [slide deck](https://301.sh/2018-gopherconuk-slides) and the [repo](https://github.com/openshift-talks/k8s-go) are useful for you; also, there is an accompanying online [Katacoda scenario](https://www.katacoda.com/mhausenblas/scenarios/k8s-go) you can use to play around.

Comment: That slide deck is really great, thanks for sharing!!

Comment: Could you add why `k8s.io/client-go` is the correct one?